# Undesirable auto complete behavior

Tags: expression-web

Microsoft Expression 4 web automatically adds code the ending or it tries to guess what code I'm typing in.

For example, if I type:

```
<a href="http://whatever.com
```

It will add:

```
</a>
```

at the end or if I type:

```
<img
```

i will get a drop down next to the crusor with a list of code that starts with `<img`

How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto 
`Tools > Page Editor Options > General Tab`

from there `uncheck`

`Automatically enclose form fields within a form`

[Source: check here](http://www.expression-web-tutorials.com/ew4/setting-up-expression-web-4.html)

Comment: thank you so much for this i will accept this once it lets me it says i have to wait 8 min

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Page Editor Options > IntelliSense
and uncheck 
Close Tag, HTML Statement Completion, CSS State Completion, etc.
From that page you can disable any form of auto-completion the program does.